# Why can't I commit all files to GitHub using 'git push'?

Tags: git, github

i am unable to commit whole project files to github by `git push - u origin main`. Say, I am in folder xyz and i did the following commands to commit and push to github:

```
mes-lia:xyz me$ git add .
mes-lia:xyz me$ git commit -m "Test Commit"
mes-lia:xyz me$ git push
```

the xyz folder has like 50+ files/folders. it is committing only few files and couple of folders in github. Also, there is not .gitignore file.

And if i try to use the command `git status` it is showing all other things not in the current folder.

Tried to fix by different ways but till now no luck. Full git status looks like the following:

```
lia:a001 me$ git status
warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    ../routerpassword_v2/themes/hugo-theme-cleanwhite
        deleted:    ../skillTest___001/.hugo_build.lock
        deleted:    ../skillTest___001/archetypes/animal/default.md
        deleted:    ../skillTest___001/themes/zen

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../../../../.CFUserTextEncoding
        ../../../../.DS_Store
        ../../../../.DVDVideoSoft/
        ../../../../.IdentityService/
        ../../../../.anaconda_backup/
        ../../../../.android/
        ../../../../.aspnet/
        ../../../../git/
        ../../../../soapui-settings.xml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Any body has any idea to fix this issue?

If i try to push the project to github it is showing nothing to push but here is in github only few files are there.

Comment: What's not getting pushed? Are you expecting uncommitted changes and untracked files to be pushed?

Comment: i want to push all files from the current folder say i am in folder "XYZ" and want to commit everything to that folder only and rest want to ignore

Comment: You don't push files. You push *commits*. If the files/changes aren't already committed locally, Git doesn't care about them.

Comment: All the files are not added because you aren't in the root. `git add .` adds everything in the current folder.

Comment: It looks like you said `git init` in your home folder, so that you now are attempting to push your entire hard drive to GitHub. Neither Git nor GitHub is going to like that. And it is very unwise to place your whole drive under Git control; you can end up losing everything.

Comment: if i type the command `pwd` it is pointing only the current folder. i am using VS code terminal to check that and to do all git task. Till yesterday, it was working nice. But from today getting that issue. Still trying lots of ways to fix. but No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted
> ```

You have a git repo in the root of your home directory on macOS. Remove the `~/.git` folder from your home directory.

Clone the Git repository to the desired location (e.g. `git clone https://…/repo.git directory`). If you've done this previously, it's likely this was caused by a `git init` in your home directory, so this step does not need to be re-done.

`cd directory` and make your desired changes in there, which can be `git add` and `git commit`. Your `git add .` adds the current directory, but `git status` showed your changes being to files in `../…`, being a parent directory therefore not added with `.`.